# Server side sorted data not showing in same order in Datatables

Tags: json, codeigniter, datatables

I am using Datatables to show data from a database. I am using CodeIgniter for serverside scripting. Here is the table image

[image]

In my serverside coding, I query to my database order by **Country** and in descending order.

I have checked CodeIgniter select query for debugging purpose i.e

```
$this->db->get_compiled_select()
```

and it is showing

```
'SELECT *
FROM `tmp`
ORDER BY `country` DESC'
```

here **tmp** is my database name, and it's performing well.

here is my json response from the database- (I can't show you the whole JSON response because of long text. That's why I use some online json parsing site to summarize my data.)

[image]

My json response showing data as per query to database i.e country column in desc order. That's why the first object is showing **"Zimbabwe"**. But in datatables it is showing other data i.e **"Andora"**.

Here is my javascript -

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable( {
                "responsive": true,
                "processing": true,
                "serverSide": true,
                "ajax": {
                    "url":  "http://localhost/adminDemo/admin/test",
                    "type": "POST"
                },
                "columnDefs" : [
                    {"width" : "20%", "targets" : 7},
                    {"width" : "30%", "targets" : 5},
                    { "orderable": false, "targets": 7 } //Don't order the action column
                ]
            } );
        } );
    </script>
```

If i set **"order": [[ 6, "desc" ]]** in datatables parameter, then it will be sorted after getting the json response. I don't want to add client-side script to order a column. I just want to use the sorted json response in datatables. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: just set `orderable` to `false` otherwise data will be shown as per default ordering defined by `datatable` itself

Comment: If I set orderable to false then I can't order the column after get the json response.

Comment: so its better to datatable ordering instead of server side ordering

Comment: That's why I am asking is there any way to the json response as it is to datatables? If I set "ordering": false then it is showing as per json response but the problem is I can't sort manually. Hope you understand bro.

Comment: may be  ordering to each individual columns helps you , see this : https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/multi_col_sort.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution to that problem is, just specify empty `[]` for `order` option.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "order": []
} );
```

> No ordering applied by DataTables during initialization. The rows are shown in the order they are read by DataTables (i.e. the original order from the DOM if DOM sourced, or the array of data if Ajax / data sourced):

Source: [**DataTable:Order**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/order)

Comment: Yes by default datatable takes the first column to sort whole data. By this way, initially, we can show the data based on json order. Thanks for your info.