# How to solve the reordering problem after disabling initial sorting of datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am disabling the initial sorting of the data tables and as I do this it disables my data table and no reordering works. What should I do to make it work?

I have tried using order feature and aaSorting feature to disable the initial sorting of the data table. But these features don't disable the sorting only but disable the complete data table.

```
$('#request_table').DataTable({
        "aaSorting":[]
        "order": [[5,"desc"]]
        //"ordering": false
        stateSave:true
});
```

I expect the output to disable sorting and I can perform sorting specifying the column name and the order.

Comment: isn't this `aaSorting` instead of `aaSoring` ??

Comment: Yes, it is. But it doesn't work either.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You want to disable initial sorting but want to integrate sorting for datatable after that??

Comment: and you also need to add comma separator after `"aaSorting":[],` for each line

Comment: Have a look at [Server side sorted data not showing in same order in Datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51076425/3814721)

Comment: I have had added separators, but then also it doesn't work. What this does is it disables data table property in the table. What I want is to disable the initial sorting and sort by giving a specific column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[aaSorting is now a legacy property, used in versions 1.9 and earlier](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref). Remove it and use the "order" property in versions 1.10 and later.

If you pass an empty array to the "order" property it will leave the initial order of the rows as they are found. This works regardless of whether the table is created in HTML or dynamically from an SQL query.

```
$('#request_table').DataTable({
    "order": []
});
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/order

Answer (score 0):

You need to add comma after each function in datatable as below:

```
$('#request_table').DataTable({
        "aaSorting":[], // It will stop initial sorting
        // "order": [[5,"desc"]], need to comment this as it is used for initial sorting order and field
        //"ordering": false,
        stateSave:true
});
```

Hope the above example helps you!!

Comment: I have tried using this but what this does is it disables data table property in the table. What I want is to disable the initial sorting and sort by giving a specific column.